# Integration inside a contour plot

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I asked this question on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/66852917/7462275) but I am not sure it is the right place. So, I asked it on math exchange.

I have a function : *z=f(x,y)* and I draw a contour plot.

For example :

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,10,11)
y=np.linspace(0,10,11)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=(X+4)*(X-14)*(Y+6)*(Y-14)/1000
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
CS= ax.contour(x,x,Z,[7],colors='black')
ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10)
```

From the contour path data points (`CS.collections[0].get_paths()[0]`), how is it possible to integrate *z* inside this area ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Please state this a math question, formatted in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz. Not sure that math exchange is the good place. This function is only an example to illustrate. I have an x,y grid with z values (measured from experiment. It is not an analytic function) and I would to integrate it around a contour plot.

Comment: MSE is not really the right place for this. You were right to post this in stack overflow first as this is primarily a software question.